# build options in automake

Tags: c, gcc, configure, automake

I download an open source from the Internet. And I build it with automake.

I see in the compilation log the following options in gcc

```
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"anydaemon\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"anydaemon\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"anydaemon\ 2.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"any.person@anydomain.com\"
```

These gcc options are generated automatically by the automake from config?

By the way the configure.ac contains the following line in the beginning:

```
AC_INIT([anydaaemon], [2.0], [any.person@anydomain.com])
```

Does the automake extract the above gcc options `PACKAGE_NAME`, `PACKAGE_VERSION` from this line?

Answer (score 0):

Automake only generates `Makefile.in` from `Makefile.am`. The rest is done in `configure` run. But yes, configure fills parameters as specified by `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`.

In other words, changing `configure.ac` wouldn't change things unless you re-generate configure script and re-run it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add: after you generate a functioning `Makefile`, it tracks `configure.ac` and re-generates `configure` automatically whenever you run `make`. So unless you break your `Makefile` to the point you can't run `make` anymore, there's no reason to run any of the preceding steps, (autoconf, automake, ./configure, etc).